# SQL query for book search

Tags: sql

I have a table with all word positions in a book

the table is like this

```
Word  PageNo  Position
----------------------
 A       1       10
 A       1       15
 B       1       13
 B       2       18
 C       2       20
```

I want to find the pages that has word A and word B

the result is page 1

I can get the answer by this query

```
select PageNo from
 (select * from t where word = 'A') a inner join
 (select * from t where word = 'B') b on a.PageNo = b.PageNo
```

but what I really want is this

```
Word  PageNo  Position
----------------------
 A       1       10
 A       1       15
 B       1       13
```

I want all rows that have pageno = (pages that have both A and B)

If i use this query

```
select * from
 (select * from t where word = 'A') a inner join
 (select * from t where word = 'B') b on a.PageNo = b.PageNo
```

here is the result

```
Word  PageNo  Position   Word  PageNo  Position
------------------------------------------------------
 A       1       10       B       1       13
 A       1       15       B       1       13
```

When i join the two lists and select all columns, six columns are shown

but i want three columns that union two lists

Is there a way i can join two lists and union the the lists?

I can do it with two selects but i want one.

Comment: It depends on concrete DBMS you're using. What is it - MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, some other DBMS?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev actually it doesn't really matter, must answers to this situation are in ANSI SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from tablename
where PageNo in
    (select PageNo
     from tablename
     where Word in ('A','B')
     group by PageNo
     having count(distinct Word) >= 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Word, PageNo, Position
FROM t
WHERE PageNo IN (SELECT PageNo
                 FROM t
                 WHERE word IN ('A', 'B')
                 GROUP BY PageNo
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word) = 2)
```

Comment: I've got an upvote, but you didn't, so I'll give you one! (And now mine was revoked...)

Answer (score 0):

if it is Oracle - you could use INTERSECT

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EXISTS()

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM YourTable s
             WHERE s.word IN ('A', 'B')
             AND t.pageno = s.pageno
             GROUP BY s.PageNo
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.word) = 2)
```